# How to stop executing the python exe file created using pyinstaller (windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have created an myprogram.exe file using the command

```
pyinstaller --onefile myprogram.py
```

I am trying to stop the execution of exe file using

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im myprogram.exe")
```

But no luck. 
1. Can any help me how can i stop the execution of exe file?
2. Also is it possible to find the already running python exe files?

Comment: I assume you are on windows. Have you tried killing the process using the task manager?

Comment: I am unable to find it in task manager

Comment: In Windows, many programs show up as python.exe

Comment: @bfris You are right!

Comment: @Madan Actually once you have created an exe, you will no more see python.exe, you'll see the name of the exe that you have generated.

Comment: @shubhendu-endu Then this statement os.system("taskkill /im myprogram.exe") does not kill my running program?

Comment: @Madan That statement makes OS to send terminate signal to the running program. Now the running program has to acknowledge this signal and need to terminate from within. But if the above statement is failing to terminate, then we include '/F' in the statement, that is to forcefully terminate the program.

Comment: @shubhendu-endu I tried. No luck

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the command.

"TASKKILL /F /IM myprogram.exe"

NOTE: You can verify whether you exe is running or not by issuing "TASKLIST"